# React - component not rendered

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am trying to render a sample data table, which I took from here:

http://adazzle.github.io/react-data-grid/examples.html#/sortable

The above table is rendered like this:

```
React.render(<Example />, document.getElementById("dummyTable"));
```

I am rendering the table in the following part of an HTML file:

```
<body>    
    <div id="dummyTable"></div>    
    <script src="Example.js"></script>    
</body>
```

I am building the JSX like this:

```
gulp.task('buildDummy', function(){
    browserify({
        entries: ['./src/app/dataTree/Example.jsx'],
        transform: [reactify],
        debug: true
    })
    .bundle()
    .pipe(source('Example.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('src/app/dataTree/'));
});
```

However, the component is not rendered.

Any ideas about why this is happening?

Comment: Can you reproduce in a fiddle or else share Js file

Comment: Have you got any errors ?